# what happens when performing a match query on a date field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Why can I perform a query of the following type:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"@timestamp": "454545645656"}}
      ]
    } 
  }
}
```

when the field type is the following one?

```
"mappings": {
  "fluentd": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
```

does it make sense? Does the query value passes the analyzer and compares the field against what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even you are using the match query on `date` field and match are analyzed means it goes through the same analyzers applied at index time on the field. As explained in [official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

But as explained in the [official ES doc on date datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html).

> Queries on dates are internally converted to range queries on this
>   long representation

You can test it yourself by using the explain=true param on your search query. More info about explain API can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-explain.html).

I did this for your search query and you can see in the result(explanation part) it shows the range query on the date field.

**URL:- /_search?explain=true**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_shard": "[date-index][0]",
                "_node": "h2H2MJd5T5-b1cUSkHVHcw",
                "_index": "date-index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "@timestamp": "454545645656"
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 1.0,
                "description": "@timestamp:[454545645656 TO 454545645656]", --> see range query
                "details": []
                }
            }
```